# Why is the spread operator needed for Math.max()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
let arr = str.split(' '); 
let lengths = arr.map(word => word.length);

console.log(Math.max(lengths));
}

findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

`console.log(Math.max(lengths))` results in `NaN`, `console.log(Math.Max(...lengths))` works. Why does lengths need to be spreaded? Math.Max takes an array as its argument, & lengths is an array? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you had a chance to review the documentation for Math.max? Please [try this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#parameters) and let us know if it helps.

Comment: [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) does not take an array as an argument. It takes zero or more numbers as arguments.

Comment: Math.max does not take an array as argument. It takes one (could be none really) or more values. `Math.max(value0, value1, /* ... ,*/ valueN)` . See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) does not take an array. It takes a set of parameters. The spread operator provides all of the values of the array as individual parameters.

```js
Math.max(...lengths)
```

is actually represented at runtime as:

```js
Math.max(lengths[0], lengths[1], etc, lengths[n])
```

Answer (score 2):

> Math.Max takes an array as its argument

This is not the case [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

> The Math.max() function returns the largest of the zero or more numbers given as input parameters, or NaN if any parameter isn't a number and can't be converted into one.